# My question was closed, why?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

I'd like to know why my question ([Quadratic terms in glmer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/440348/quadratic-terms-in-glmer)) was closed here.

I think my question is not off-topic because it's about statistics and not about the programming itself. My question is regarding the quadratic and multiplication coefficients. So if I understand the theory, the programming is just putting those in the R function. In my question, it doesn't really matter if what package or function I'm using, because my question is regarding the logistic regression model coefficients!

My question was:

> I'm looking for some references that explain step by step how to model logistic regression to longitudinal data (repeated measurements) in R.
>   I know that I can use the "*lme4*" package and the function "*glmer*" for generalized linear mixed models, and I use it to add random effects. But I've read some stuff and sometimes people add quadratic terms and multiply and sometimes they don't. Can someone clarify me on this?
>
> For example, on the book "Applied Longitudinal Analysis by Fitzmaurice", in chapter 14.7, he models the logistic regression for a dataset like this:
>
> *model1 <- glmer(y ~ time + time2 + trt.time + trt.time2 + (1 | id), family=binomial, nAGQ=50, na.action=na.omit)*
>
> where,
>
> *$time2 <- time^2$*
>
> *$trt.time <- trt \times time$*
>
> *$trt.time2 <- trt*time2$*
>
> Why doesn't he simply use *model1 <- glmer(y ~ time + trt+ (1 | id), family=binomial, nAGQ=50, na.action=na.omit)* ???
>   I run this last model in R and the AIC and BIC are basically the same.
>
> This is the type of questions that I'm having concerning the R code on this matter. I can't find many literature with R on logistic regression for longitudinal data, and this all very confusing. Can someone explain me when to use quadratic terms, or multiply/add them? Or recommend me a reference.
>
> I also found this topic [LINK](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/200280/quadratic-terms-in-logistic-regression) but didn't help much.
>
> Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems out-of-date. The question is not closed as I write. But emphasising again and again that you want advice on what to do in R was presumably what triggered any closure. The trick is to write a question without any reference to software whatsoever!  Otherwise the question of when to add quadratic terms is fair, but a good answer is hard beyond whenever the data or theory seem to imply that they are a good idea.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question concerned is no longer closed.